# No puedo desencapsular los datos de un JSON en javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy con un problema que no puedo solucionar de ninguna forma. Desde un json obtengo datos de productos que uso para escribir la tienda en el DOM, todo funciona como debe. El problema es cuando quiero tomar los objetos del JSON y sacarlos fuera de la función para meterlos en un array y así poder ordenarlos de diferentes maneras y pasarlos (a través de botones de la tienda) a un array que es un carrito de compras. Probé de todas las formas que se me ocurrieron y todo me devuelve undefined. Si alguien me puede ayudar a ver que estoy haciendo mal, se lo agradeceré infinitamente.

El código es el siguiente:

```
// constructor de objeto Producto //
class Producto {
    constructor (id, form_id, titulo, nombre, descripcion, descripcion_mid, descripcion_long, precio, cantidad, imagen, altimg, stockDisponible) {
        this.id = id;
        this.form_id = form_id;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.descripcion_mid = descripcion_mid;
        this.descripcion_long = descripcion_long;
        this.precio = parseFloat(precio);
        this.cantidad = parseInt(cantidad);
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.altimg = altimg;
        this.stockDisponible = parseInt(stockDisponible);
        this.subtotal = this.precio * this.cantidad;
    }
}

// acá quiero guardar uno por uno los objetos del JSON//
let listaDeProductos = new Array;

//acá obtengo los datos del JSON y dibujo la tienda dinámicamente,
//me funciona como lo esperaba, el problema es cuando quiero sacar los objetos
//fuera y guardarlos en el array, pruebe lo que pruebe me da undefined

const pedido = new XMLHttpRequest();
pedido.open('GET', 'scripts/productos.json', true);
pedido.send();
pedido.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //console.log(pedido.responseText);
        let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        // esto es lo que no me está funcionando
        datos.forEach( (elemento) => {
            console.log(elemento);
            let producto =  new Producto (`${elemento.id}`, `${elemento.form_id}`, `${elemento.titulo}`, `${elemento.nombre}`, `${elemento.descripcion}`, `${elemento.descripcion_mid}`, `${elemento.descripcion_long}`, `${elemento.precio}`, `${elemento.cantidad}`, `${elemento.imagen}`, `${elemento.altimg}`, `${elemento.stockDisponible}`);
            listaDeProductos.push(producto);
            console.log(producto);
            }
        )
        // estos logs me muestran bien los datos pero afuera de la funcion da undefined
        //console.log(datos);
        for (item of datos) {
            //console.log(producto);
            $("#mostrar_productos").append(`
            <article class="productos__item">
            <div>
                <img src="${item.imagen}" alt="${item.altimg}">
            </div>
            <div class="productos__item--descripcion">
                <h3 tabindex=0>${item.titulo}</h3>
                <p tabindex=0>${item.descripcion_mid}</p>
                <div class="productos__item--descripcion--botones">
                    <a tabindex=0 href="#${item.id}_popup" class="saber">Saber mas</a>
                    <a tabindex=0 class="agregar" id="cnj-btn">agregar al carrito</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
            <div id="${item.id}_popup" class="ventana__popup">
                <div class="contenedor__popup">
                    <div class="popup"><a tabindex=0 href="" class="cerrar__popoup">X</a>
                        <div><img src="${item.imagen}" alt="${item.altimg}"></div>
                            <div class="popup--descripcion">
                                <div tabindex=0 class="titulo">${item.titulo}</div>
                                <p tabindex=0>${item.descripcion_long}</p>
                            <div tabindex=0 class="importe__popup">$950.-</div>
                            <a tabindex=0 class="agregar" id="zrt-btn2">agregar al carrito</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            `);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo pude solucionar con

```
fetch('scripts/productos.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { let fetchedData = [];
                    data.forEach( (elemento) => {fetchedData.push(elemento);});
                    sessionStorage.setItem('itemsDeLaTienda', JSON.stringify(fetchedData));
    });
```

guardando el contenido del json en el session Storage y cargandolo en un array del mismo js. Cargó correctamente y puedo acceder a todos los datos del array.